# Vba: Highlight Cell based on Partial Match

Tags: excel, vba, match, highlight, partial

I have a good solution to highlighting cells based on an exact condition. I'm trying to highlight based on partial matches. For Example: A1= Dodge. A2 = Durango, A3 = Dart.

How can I do a partial match of lets say "dodg" and "duran" and "dar"  then don't highlight the cell but every other cell. Basically if the partial match is missing, then highlight the cell in the entire column.

The following highlights "Durango" if there is a match:

```
Sub Highlight()

Dim Highlight As Range
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set w = ws.Rows(1).Find("Dodge", lookat:=xlWhole)
 If Not w Is Nothing Then
    For Each Highlight In ws.Range(w, ws.Cells(Rows.Count, w.Column).End(xlUp)).Cells
            If Highlight = "Durango" Then
                Highlight.Interior.Color = 65535
            End If
        Next Highlight
 End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Well for starters, `lookat:=xlWhole` won't work for a *partial* match, right?

Comment: Correct, even when I do xlPart, it still doesnt seem to pick up

Comment: Correct, because `Dodge` is not found in `dodg`... Sounds like maybe you want a [fuzzy match](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011), or change the lookup value to be `"dodg"`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use

```
If Highlight Like "Durango" then...
```

Like will search the cell for that word so it doesn't have to be an exact match to the whole cell, just contain that word or partial word using the "*". So in your case set up a variable for match then use

```
keyword = Cells(whatever cell your search word is entered into)
keyword = "*" & keyword & "*"
If Highlight Like keyword then
    'code to highlight whatever cells or _
    ' Set a Range and highlight the whole range.
end if
```

Comment: realized the wildcards were missing as I clicked post. I've edited to correct. I was wrong about the UCase....i'll edit that one too.

Comment: I was able to modify your example: keyword = "dur"
            keyword2 = "Dur"
            keyword3 = "Dar"
            keyword4 = "dar"
            keyword = "*" & keyword & "*"
            keyword2 = "*" & keyword2 & "*"
            keyword3 = "*" & keyword3 & "*"
            keyword4 = "*" & keyword4 & "*"
           
            If Not Highlight Like keyword And _
                Not Highlight Like keyword2 And _
                Not Highlight Like keyword3 And _
                Not Highlight Like keyword4 Then
            Highlight.Interior.Color = 65535

Comment: I may have not done the most efficient process based on your recommendation but it works, thank you!